# How to turn a card from front to back and then back to front on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to coding and need help solving a problem. I added my HTML, CSS and JS files below. My goal is to build a website and when the user scrolls down from the brown section to the orange section, I want the card to turn on its axis from front to back, pause two seconds (I need code for the pause too), and then turn again on its axis from back to front (back to the start position).

As you can see, in my JavaScript file, the card turns from front to back, but I don’t know how to code it so that it turns from back to front again. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 1) {
        entry.target.classList.add('fliped')
      } else {
        entry.target.classList.remove('fliped')
      }











    })
  }, {
    threshold: [1]
  },
)

const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.flip-card')

cards.forEach(card => {
  observer.observe(card)
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background-color: brown;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.two {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flip-card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(90px) scale(0.91);
  transform: translateZ(90px) scale(0.91);
}

.fliped .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="one">

</section>

<section class="two">

  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <h1>Font</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>Back</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please familiarize yourself with the editor around here. Always best to post code as snippets, so we can use it to test things and answering. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done by using a setTimout function which removes the class after 2000ms, see example below.

```js
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
  entries => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.intersectionRatio >= 1) {
        entry.target.classList.add('fliped');
        setTimeout(() => { // setTimeout
          entry.target.classList.remove('fliped') // to remove class
        }, 2000) // after 2000ms
      } else {
        entry.target.classList.remove('fliped')
      }
    })
  }, {
    threshold: [1]
  }, )

const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.flip-card')

cards.forEach(card => {
  observer.observe(card)
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

.one {
  background-color: brown;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.two {
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flip-card {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.8s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(90px) scale(0.91);
  transform: translateZ(90px) scale(0.91);
}

.fliped .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<section class="one">

</section>

<section class="two">

  <div class="flip-card">
    <div class="flip-card-inner">
      <div class="flip-card-front">
        <h1>Front</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="flip-card-back">
        <div class="content">
          <h1>Back</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: a thousand thank yous!!!! It worked!